# how to convert number to string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I want to convert a number to string in JS, which is the best and recommaded way to do that?

I have tried the method shared on W3school so far. but want to know the recommaded methods from experts

Comment: use the [Number.prototype.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) method - I'm curious, what IS  *the method shared on W3school*? Knowing W3school, it's probably wrong - I would avoid that site like the joke it is, and get better documentation form MDN

Comment: personally, I always use `toString` since you can specify a `radix`

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `var str = '' + num`  is the fastest way to convert a number to a string (num being the number variable).

```js
let num = 5
var str = '' + num
```

(results based on this benchmark: http://jsben.ch/#/ghQYR)

Comment: by *fastest* you mean *least code* - unless you've done some *benchmarks* to qualify your assertion :D

Comment: The results are based on a benchmark: http://jsben.ch/#/ghQYR

Comment: ouch, I've been schooled :p

Comment: Hehe, don't worry bout it

Comment: interestingly, at least in firefox, `"" + num + ""` is fastest and `"" + num` is slowest!!! though, in reality, the speed difference between those for "methods" is insignificant - and edge/chrome fastest depends swaps between those two in each run

Comment: It does differ from browser to browser, but most people use Google Chrome. Honeslty, I don't understand why browsers intrepret all the possible ways of doing this diffirently. Why would adding 2 empty spaces take less time then adding one?

Comment: correction, firefox order changes on every run, the differences are so minor

Comment: Yes, you would have to run the code millions of times to actually see a diffirence in timing. (on the web)

Comment: Table is 100% faster if fits in CPU cache: http://jsben.ch/F5sVg But if numbers are too big, you can simply memoize it in an ```{}``` table object. It should work with similar performance because too big numbers would require more time on other methods too. Maybe only worthy for big-integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in function: `toString():`

Example:
`let number = 3` 
`let stringed_number = number.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

All of these will work:

```js
`${num}`
num.toString()
'' + num
String(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using .[toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) if you want pretty formatting, like commas or periods for grouping.

However if you know you don't want pretty formatting you should use .toString